# What is $7-\frac{12}{7-\frac{12}{7-\frac{12}{7-\cdots}}}$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, continued-fractions

What is $7-\cfrac{12}{7-\cfrac{12}{7-\cfrac{12}{7-\cdots}}}$?

Conventional methods of solving these types of problems tell me to do as follows:

Let
$$x =7-\cfrac{12}{7-\cfrac{12}{7-\cfrac{12}{7-\cdots}}}$$

Then $x = 7-\frac{12}{x}$. Then the solution is $x=3, 4$. How do I know which one to pick?

Comment: There is a third possibility, which is that it doesn't converge.

Comment: What makes an expression like this not converge but something like
$1 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{1 + \cdots}}} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ converge?

Comment: @Cheerful Parsnip : What is third possibility ?

Comment: @HKLee that it doesn't converge

Comment: @Anonymous: There are theorems about the convergence of standard continued fractions, where the numerators are all 1 and you are adding each time. Generalized continued fractions do not always converge.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(EDITED)

If $f(x) = 7 - 12/x$, then $f'(3) = 4/3$ while $f'(4) = 3/4$.  Since $|f'(3)| > 1$, $3$ is a repelling fixed point of the iteration $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$, while since $|f'(4)|< 1$, $4$ is an attracting fixed point.  Thus if you don't start exactly at $3$, the iterations won't converge to $3$, but they will converge to $4$ at least if you eventually get close enough to $4$.

The boundary points of the immediate basin of attraction of an attracting  fixed point can be $\pm \infty$, a singular point (here $0$), a repelling fixed point,
a point mapped to one of those, or a $2$-cycle.  Here there are no $2$-cycles, and the basin of attraction
is $(3, \infty)$.  Thus if you start, or ever get, anywhere $> 3$, you end up 
approaching the limit $4$.

Answer (score 3):

The practical answer is to compute a few terms of the series and see which root it is converging to.  Make a column in a spreadsheet starting with $7$ and then below $=7-12/above$ and copy down.  It is clearly converging to $4$

If you do the above, which is a good exploration even if you want a rigorous solution, you should note that the iterations are always greater than $4$ and decreasing.  You can show that if one iteration is greater than $4$, the next is less but still greater than $4$.  Now you have a sequence that is monotonic and bounded below by $4$, so it must converge.  You have shown that if it converges it is to either $3$ or $4$, so you are done.